# htaccess remove html and php duplicated is not working

Tags: .htaccess

this snippet works fine for removing php extension

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However, if I add html condition, it will not work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead, in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}      !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php   -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !\.php   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %{REQUEST_URI}.php   [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}      !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html  -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !\.html  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %{REQUEST_URI}.html  [NC,L]
```

You should be aware the implementation in your code works **only when the request doesn't have a trailing slash**. I just modified your code to work, but I think it's worth nothing that problem. For example:

For a request like `http://example.com/filename/`, the file to match with condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php   -f` is `filename/.php`. That file can't exist, therefore, the respective rule will be never used.

#### Option to remove the trailing slash when present:

Add these lines after `RewriteEngine On` in the previous code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /(.*[^/]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*              /%1          [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I got `Error 500`

Comment: I had a copy+paste error that inserted spaces between `!` and `-d`. Maybe that's the problem. I modified the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-) it works like a charm. Is that possible to add a trailing slash at the end ?

Comment: How can I add a rule for trailing slash. I put this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+[^/]) [NC] RewriteRule .  %1/  [L,R=301]` a slash added but page wont work

Comment: Updated my answer with an option to remove the trailing slash.

Comment: This is the best answer! I may have ticked twice as a right answer if it is allowed :-)